# How to load custom tab icon in createBottomTabNavigator() in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I am using TabNavigator in StackNavigator, i am able to pass props to TabNavigator from StackNavigator , which has four tabs.

one of the tab which is named profile, has image icon, loading from URL.
i can show image from URL whenever i come from Login or Splash screen.
but the problem is once user change profile picture, i can't update the profile icon in profile tab.

here is my code:

This is Main StackNavigator:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Landing from '../screens/onboarding/Landing';
import PhoneLogin from '../screens/onboarding/PhoneLogin';
import EnterCode from '../screens/onboarding/EnterCode';
import Home from './HomeTaBNavigator';


export default createStackNavigator({

Landing: {
    screen: Landing,
    navigationOptions: { header: null, }
},
PhoneLogin: {
    screen: PhoneLogin,
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
},
EnterCode: {
    screen: EnterCode,
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
},
Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
},

});
```

This is TabNavigator:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, TabBarBottom } from 'react-navigation';
import Feed from '../screens/home/Feed';
// import Notification from '../screens/home/Notification';
import Notification from './NotificationNavigator';
// import Profile from '../screens/home/Profile';
import Profile from './ProfileNavigator';
// import Search from '../screens/home/Search';
import Search from './SearchNavigator';
import { Colors } from '../theme';
import ImageProgress from 'react-native-image-progress';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  iconProfileImg: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderRadius: 12,
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    borderRadius: 12,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    alignContent: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },


});

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: {
    screen: Feed,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        let url = navigation.getParam('userProfileImageUrl');
        console.log('userProfileImage in Home BottomTabBar: ', url);

        return (focused ? <Image source={require('Frenemys/src/assets/tab_bar_icons/tab_1_active.png')} /> : <Image source={require('Frenemys/src/assets/tab_bar_icons/tab_1.png')} />)
      }
    })
  },
  Search: {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        let url = navigation.getParam('userProfileImageUrl');
        console.log('userProfileImage in Search BottomTabBar: ', url);

        return (focused ? <Image source={require('Frenemys/src/assets/tab_bar_icons/tab_2_active.png')} /> : <Image source={require('Frenemys/src/assets/tab_bar_icons/tab_2.png')} />)
      }
    })
  },
  Notification: {
    screen: Notification,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        let url = navigation.getParam('userProfileImageUrl');
        console.log('userProfileImage in Notification BottomTabBar: ', url);
        return (focused ? <Image source={require('Frenemys/src/assets/tab_bar_icons/tab_3_active.png')} /> : <Image source={require('Frenemys/src/assets/tab_bar_icons/tab_3.png')} />)
      }
    })
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        let url = navigation.getParam('userProfileImageUrl');
        console.log('userProfileImage in Profile BottomTabBar: ', url);
        return (
          <View style={{ marginTop: -8 }}>
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
              <ImageProgress
                style={styles.iconProfileImg}
                source={{ uri: url }}
                renderError={(error) => {
                  console.log('error load image: ', error)
                  return (
                    <Image
                      style={styles.iconProfileImg}
                      source={require('Frenemys/src/assets/additional_icons/profile_fallback.jpg')}
                    />
                  )
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        )
      }

    }),
  },
}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: Colors.app_green,
      inactiveTintColor: Colors.inactive_tab_black,
      showLabel: false,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      },
    },

    tabStyle: {
      width: 100,
      //backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
    // tabBarComponent: props => <TabBar navigation={props.navigation}/>,
    lazy: true,
    initialRouteName: 'Feed',
  });
```

Now when i change profile picture in EditProfile.js which is child component of Profile Stack Navigator, Now how can i update icon in profile tab??

EditProfile:
i am saving user data in AsyncStorage.

```
 saveUser = async (fromImageUpload, responseData) => {
    try {
      const data = fromImageUpload ? responseData.data.profile : responseData.data;
      console.log('get user: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(AsyncKeyss.USER, JSON.stringify(data));
      return data;

    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

I am able to update profile icon in profile tab whenever i come from Login screen, as i told above.

```
 navigation.navigate(NavigationKeys.Home, { userProfileImageUrl: userImage });
```

Comment: Please show how you change the profile picture, in wich component

Comment: @Vencovsky see my updated code.

Comment: @AbdulSalam. Where are you defining Colors? I'm trying to pass in a global constant to tabBarOptions and it's not working. Only works when you hard code the value.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you get a param like `let url = navigation.getParam('userProfileImageUrl');` you can just set the param (update the value) when you change the profile picture.

Just call

```
navigation.setParams({userProfileImageUrl: newUserProfileImageUrl })
```

With the new image url and it will be updated.

Comment: yeah, i was thinking about this, but Profile and its child navigation has no params like userProfileImageUrl, only the first child of Home StackNavigator has params with key userProfileImageUrl.
so where to set these params??

Comment: @AbdulSalam anywhere that have `navigation` ?